# AutoFac Controller does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

Hi I want to switch from Ninject to AutoFac but I'm having some problems. Error is:

> Controllers.API.Basic.AddressController' does not have a default
>   constructor

I register this at startup:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType<AddressRepository>().As<IBaseRepository<Address>>();

builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

IContainer container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

and this is my controller:

```
public class AddressController : GenericBaseController<Address>
{
    public AddressController(IBaseRepository<Address> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }
```

Am I missing something? This worked with Ninject.

Comment: if you are using webapi you need to use : `var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;` https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it:

```
// Set the dependency resolver for Web API.
var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;
```

After I set this it worked